# Text with outline and text shadow

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to create following font style. If not possible I want to be as close to this style as possible. I need to support IE so I cannot use `text-stroke`.

[image: Text shadow with outline]

The closest way I have come is to use multiple `text-shadow` attributes, for example:

```css
h1 {
   color: #2e536f;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 7em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-shadow:
     -1px -1px 0 #fff,
      1px -1px 0 #fff,
     -1px 1px 0 #fff,
      1px 1px 0 #fff,
     -2px -5px 0px #ff7c7c;
}

body {
    background: #2e536f; 
}
```

```html
<h1>Zwei</h1>
```

While it does several tasks, I cannot make the color transparent, to reveal the text shadow behind it.

How can I solve this?

Comment: why not use an svg?

Comment: @JacobGray consider having a longer text. Then you could either scale the text down on mobile devices (which could become really small) or create several versions with different line breaks.

So creating a SEO friendly css solution seems to be more scaleable, especially if there are multiple headlines with the same style.

Comment: I think this would be helpful to you to achieve this solution. http://jsfiddle.net/kovalchik/yJff9/

Comment: I came quite for, the only problem is always eliminating `text-stroke`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRvpqN?editors=1100

Comment: [https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text] .This might help

Comment: @MarianRick [google indexes SVG content and text since 2010](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/08/google-now-indexes-svg.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+blogspot/amDG+(Official+Google+Webmaster+Central+Blog)&utm_content=Google+Reader)

Comment: I think that I could achieve this using only CSS and not using text-stroke, but the techniques needed won't work in IE either

Answer (score 4):

If you need to support IE, your best bet is to go for SVG. You can easily **give stroke and/or shadow to text** to make the exact style you are looking for. This can fit titles but might be a hassle for text that spans several lines though.
Here is your example with an inline SVG:

```css
body {
  background: #2e536f;
}
svg {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 3">
  <text font-size="3" x="1.5" y="2.5" dx="0" dy="0" fill="#FF7C7C">ZWEI</text>
  <text font-size="3" x="1.5" y="2.5" dx="0.1" dy="0.15" fill="transparent" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0.08">ZWEI</text>
</svg>
```

*Note that using SVG (even for titles) doesn't impact SEO and [google indexes SVG since 2010](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/08/google-now-indexes-svg.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20blogspot/amDG%20(Official%20Google%20Webmaster%20Central%20Blog)&utm_content=Google%20Reader)*

Comment: While this is a great approach, a css solution would be much more flexible. For example if you replace the text with a whole sentence, the svg scales down and becomes really small. Although there are no line breaks at all. Using `text-stroke` its no problem at all. Maybe I just need to let some time pass by until its supported by microsoft. (Text-stroke version: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRvpqN?editors=1100)

Comment: I see what you mean @MarianRick but there is no way I know of to achieve your aim style and support IE at the same time.

Comment: thats sad ;) thanks for your suggestion. Although seeing google indexes SVGs is good to know!

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    background: #2e536f; 
}

h1 {
   color: #2e536f;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 7em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-shadow:
     -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px 1px 0 #fff, 1px 1px 0 #fff, 2px -5px 0px #ff7c7c
}
```

```html
<h1>Zwei</h1>
```

Can this be close to your expected output?